# R Check for categorical variable value with taking NA into account

Tags: r

To check if a categorical variable has one of a number of values, I'll use `%in%`, however, this does not handle NAs, instead returning `FALSE`.

For example:

```
foo <- c('a', 'b', NA, 'c')
foo %in% c('a', 'c')
```

Returns `TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE`, when one might expect it to return `TRUE FALSE NA TRUE`, since many other boolean statements (`==`, `>`) return `NA` in cases where one of the values is.

Is there a better way of having this `NA` behaviour without having to manually check each possibility? I.e.

```
foo == 'a' | foo == 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace(foo %in% c('a', 'c'), is.na(foo), NA)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

OR

```
do.call("|", lapply(c("a", "c"), function(x) x == foo))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

Comment: While this works, is there not a single function that do the same job?